# Property 'CGImage' cannot be found in forward class object 'UIImage'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I got this error on :

```
        self.contents = (id)_stillImage.CGImage;
```

_stillImage is UIImage and class is `CALayer`.

How to solve ?

Comment: Why is it casted as `id`

Comment: becoz content is id type

Comment: can you write at-least 4 to 5 lines of code pls

Comment: you might have wanted to write `... = (id)(_stillImage.CGImage);`, as `id` has no such property as `CGImage`.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as `image.CGImage` where image is a UIImage object.
You can further casting it into type id by bridging it. 
But here you want to add UIImage object to a layer.
So just use this code.

```
self.view.layer.contents = (__bridge id) myImage.CGImage
```

If you are subclassing the layer the use.

```
self.contents = (__bridge id) myImage.CGImage
```

Answer (score 0):

`_stillImage` is `CALayer` which belong to `QuartzCore framework`, so if you have not added or imported to your project then it can cause error you got.

Try after,

Adding `QuartzCore framework` to your project if you have not added.

then,

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

import it into your `viewController` file.

Hope this will help:)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is can not find the UIImage.h, you just need do is

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`